# It does not work when I use MPMoviePlayerController to play mp4

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, mp4, xcode4.5

```
NSURL *fileURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/start.m4v",  [[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath]]];    
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerController];
[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
moviePlayerController.fullscreen=YES;
[moviePlayerController play];
moviePlayerController.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeFill;
```

It dose not work.Always white,nothing at all!What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your m4v file is supported? What codec are you using?

Comment: start.mp4 is in the resource folder. I also tried the name start.mp4, it also does not work.Always blank. Anything wrong?